# GNU parallel not accepting arguments from man page

Tags: unix, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

Why doesn't this work?

```
> echo "asdfghjkl" | parallel --pipe --cat wc {}
parallel: Error: Command (--cat) starts with '-'. Is this a wrong option?
```

It is taken (almost) straight from the docs (http://www.gnu.org/software/parallel/man.html)

Adding --gnu does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Which version are you running?

```
parallel --version
```

parallel-20140422 is the first official version supporting `--cat`, and the online man page is always for the newest release. To read the man page for older versions install the older version and do:

```
man parallel
```

Comment: I had updated through the package manager, to what I thought was the latest version and it still wasn't working. I upgraded manually and it worked. Thanks